# Java code to reduce vertical space between lines

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am creating a PDF with some content in it. My requirement is to reduce the space between lines while creating the PDF so that more number of lines fit in single page. How can I reduce the space between lines?

```
    Document document = null;
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream("Paragraph2.pdf"));
    document.open();
    
    Font font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.COURIER,12);
   
    //code to get the content to show in the document
       .....
   for (final MyDocument document: doc)
   {
    if (doc.getDocumentLines() != null)
    {
    final DocumentLines documentLines = doc.getLetterLines();
    for (final String line : documentines.getDocumentLine())
    {
       document.add(new Paragraph(line,font));
    } 
    }
   }
```

### Update

I have used below line to reduce the space between lines.

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph(12,line,font);
```

When I used leading with value 12 in my code, blank space between lines got reduced and more lines from page2 got shifted to page1. But the issue is when I gave `Paragraph p = new Paragraph(12,line,font)` lines got shifted to page1 but I can see blank space/blank lines are in page2 as shown in the image below.

[image]

In the image above, ADDITIONAL INFORMATION line should be printed from top of the page, we can notice the blank space in page 2 in the above image.

When I set the leading with value 11 `Paragraph(11,line,font)`, I noticed their is no additional space left as shown in the image below. But ADDITIONAL INFORMATION line was also in page1 which I was expecting in page2. For me leading with 12 will give the expected output, but as shown in image1 there are blank lines in page2 which is an issue to resolve. How can I overcome this blank space issue?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space between two lines is called the *leading*.

You change it with the `setleading()` method.

For instance:

```
p.setleading(15);
```

Note: by default, iText takes 1.5 times the font size. If the font size is 12, the leading will be 18 by default.

You can also set the leading in the constructor: http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/Paragraph.html#Paragraph-float-java.lang.String-com.itextpdf.text.Font-

```
document.add(new Paragraph(15, line, font));
```

Comment: i tried with document.add(new Paragraph(15, line, font)); in my code, space got reduced between lines and some more lines from page2 got fit in page1, but i noticed many blank lines (or white space) in page2.  I was assuming the number of lines which got fit in page 1 that many blank lines it left in page2 and then started to print the document. Have anyone noticed this before. Thankyou.

Comment: You'll have to provide a better description of your additional problem. The concept of *blank lines* doesn't really exist in PDF, so it's hard for me to understand what you're saying. Maybe you are looking to use `ColumnText` in simulation mode?

Comment: Please see my edited post. I have added additional information with images which gives more clarity about the issue. thanks.

Comment: Er... I see that you had a question and that question was answered. Now you have a new question, so you updated the original question? It doesn't work that way on Stack Overflow. People willing to help you with answers don't look at questions with accepted answer. If you have a new question, post a new question. Don't update an old question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick demo, see if that will give you the right idea

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class ParagraphSpaceDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Document document = new Document();

    try {
        String name = "ParagraphSetting.pdf";
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(name);
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fos);
        document.open();

        String content = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

        // Setting paragraph line spacing to 32
        Paragraph para1 = new Paragraph(32);

        // Setting the space before and after the paragraph
        para1.setSpacingBefore(50);
        para1.setSpacingAfter(50);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            para1.add(new Chunk(content));
        }
        document.add(para1);

//irrelevant code
}
```

Comment: You are looking for the *leading*; see my answer.