# limited content

Tags: java

I am creating a pdf with some content using iText API in java. I want to leave the last line of page1 as blank and again starting printing the content from page2. Is their any way in iText API to do so.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it work to call

```
document.newPage()
```

once you have printed everything you need to have on page 1, and then continue with the content for page 2?

Comment: Yes, I also interpret the question like this. If this answer isn't accepted by the OP, the question should be clarified.

Comment: @Markus Fischer - No I cant use document.newPage(), as the content is dynamic content.

Comment: By any chance can we set the number of lines to display in page1?

Comment: Do not double-post the same question (see [set number of lines to display dynamically in PDF page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39351589). In that "new" question, you don't give us any more information about `DocumentLines`. If we'd know that every `line` would be short enough so that it doesn't break, and if we'd know the total number of lines, we could suggest to define the leading as the height of the page divided by the number of lines. However, depending on the nature of `DocumentLines`, the output could be very ugly. Your question needs more clarification: **What do you want???**

Comment: @BrunoLowagie - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39256646/java-code-to-reduce-space-between-lines. That is the exact problem I am facing. Please suggest, how can I remove the blank space/lines which are displayed in page2.

Comment: @javaUser Which blank space / lines? Show us what you mean. Your description doesn't allow us to imagine which result you get versus which result you desire.